# How to return a list from a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code:

```
def primes(n):
  acc = []
  return do_primes(range(2,n,1), acc)

def do_primes(xs, acc):
  if xs:
    head, tail = xs[0], xs[1:]
    acc.append(head)
    do_primes([x for x in xs if x % head != 0], acc)
  else:
    return acc
```

Invoking the code yields to None:

```
>>> primes(10)
None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` once more:

```
def do_primes(xs, acc):
  if xs:
    head, tail = xs[0], xs[1:]
    acc.append(head)
    return do_primes([x for x in xs if x % head != 0], acc)
  else:
    return acc
```